# VLC dark mode on Windows 11 desktop?

Tags: windows, vlc-media-player, themes, dark-mode

According to [this site](https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/linux/dark-mode-in-vlc-player), VLC on GNU is centrally themed via Qt, but for Windows I've only found ["use the eDark skin"](https://www.turnoffthelights.com/support/browser-extension/how-to-enable-vlc-dark-mode/), which only works when opening that vlt file with VLC and lacks my custom controls. Is there a way to get the "force theme" option or invert just VLC's interface colors on Windows 11?

Comment: There are many other dark skins. Have you tried them? They could be more up-to-date with controls. You can sort by `last updated date` here: https://www.videolan.org/vlc/skins.php?sort=date_mod

Comment: Anyone know of a good dark skin that will actually maximize to the full screen size (and not have teeny tiny buttons as a result) when viewed on an UHD display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't figured out WSL compilation or reinstalled my VirtualBox yet, but according to [this page](https://www.qt.io/blog/dark-mode-on-windows-11-with-qt-6.5) `vlc-3.0.18\modules\gui\qt\qt.cpp` might just need `QQuickStyle::setStyle("fusion");` instead of `QApplication::setStyle(s_style);` on line 641 #ifdef _WIN32. Maybe setting `MainWindow/QtStyle` somewhere would work as well.

As for the skin not working, enable "Skinnable Interface" in Advanced Preferences:

[image: Skinnable Interface checkbox]

Somehow that also comes with a terminal window, even after selecting the default theme which doesn't stick (until [`vlc --reset-config`](https://askubuntu.com/a/771301/42522)):

[image: VLC adding a terminal window to its skinned interface]

I'll stick with [PotPlayer](http://potplayer.daum.net/) for now.

Answer (score 0):

The eDark skin can be modified according to your needs, or you may
create your own skin for VLC.

The tool to use is
[VLC media player Skin Editor](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/skineditor.html).
You can download the latest build at the
[download page](http://get.videolan.org/skin-editor/0.8.5/).

This is what you can do :

> **Features**
>
> - Absolutely no XML knowledge required
> - Add images and fonts directly from files
> - Helpful visual aid to create SubBitmaps
> - Direct preview of how the skin will look
> - Preview of how your skin looks in different situations (playing, paused, etc.)
> - Import and export of VLT files (packed VLC Skins)
> - Easily add and modify items of your skin
> - Position your skin's items with the mouse or the arrow keys
> - Hierarchic display of skins content
> - Makes the creation of action sequences comfortable
> - Can handle all skins created by hand
> - Available in different languages

Comment: That looked promising, but it doesn't show added windows or even a dialog to edit an existing theme. 2009 software probably incompatible with Windows 11.